# Add a segment inside WordPress URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I want to be able to add a segment to WordPress permalinks, so that my website's url changes like this:

instead of http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/postname/

it should read http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/coolstuff/postname

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress Backend

Go to `Settings -> Permlinks` OR 'yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php'

Choose last option: `custom permalink` and add `/coolstuff/%postname%/`

That should work for your case.